# Facebook Log In with virtual QWERTY in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, authentication, keyboard, virtual

I am working in a project which uses the Facebook graph-api to log in. I have the requirement of only using a virtual keyboard (no hardware will be present). I have looked everywhere, but can't find a solution for adding a virtual qwerty keyboard to the popUp.

I can put the keyboard into a popup, or I could add the qwerty keyboard into the screen with the addChild() method, but I still have one problem: the virtual keyboard does not focus to the textInputs of the popup and when i press a key, everything "explooota".

---

Anyone knows how i could solve the focus problem?

I mean... when i prees the virtual key, i call a java function wich simulate a physical keyboard, but i lose the focus into the facebook input text and the letter is not in the textinput... and i dont know how to recover the focus...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem with a desktop app written in C#. I can only answer for a windows based application. Assuming you are working on a desktop app and that you are showing the login in a web browser control you can use the **SendInput API** to direct keyboard-like input to a field in the browser. We had our own custom keyboard; I don't think you will be able to use the built-in on-screen keyboard MS provides.

We had a windows form that hosted a web browser control and the keyboard custom control. The user touches the field that they want to fill in. The user types their input using the on-screen keyboard, the keyboard uses SendInput to send the appropriate character for the key that was touched to the web browser control. Other problems to look out for:

- the facebook login form takes a lot of space, having both the keyboard and login visible at the same time is difficult
- sending non-ascii characters; see this for help ([SendInput sequence to create unicode character fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225005/sendinput-sequence-to-create-unicode-character-fails))
- the user will have to touch to select the input field
- there are other links on the FB login page you may want to restrict (like create an account)
- an on-screen keyboard where touching the key doesn't steal focus from the browser field

These can all be solved but they are not trivial.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help rlm2!!! I will try what you said and then i tell you whats happen... Thanks you so mucho for you great answer!

Comment: The answer was very helpfull! thaks you so much for your time!

Comment: hello... finnally i implement what you tell me, but unfortunatelly i have the last problem taht you enum, when i touch the virtual qwerty i los focus on the browser and the letter is not written there... do you know how could i fix this??? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Matias, I'd open a new question for tagged for Flex that asks how to create a button that doesn't steal focus.

Comment: @rml2 Ok Thanks you so much... i will be looking for the question... Thanks!